# View photos in folder one by one and move, based on one keystroke, to particular folder, depending on keystroke

Tags: java, javascript, php, sorting, photos

I searched a bit and found numerous photo sorting mechanisms, by date, exif info, etc. But not this. I would like to view on the screen, one at a time, each photo in directory named say "2sort", and then type a letter on the keyboard that moves the photo in a folder tied to the particular letter.

Example: view first image, type letter "r", image is moved to folder "aa"
View second image, type letter "s", image is moved to folder named "bb"
third image, type "r", image is moved to folder "aa"

there used to be a java program called "jpicsort" that looked like it might do that but I cannot locate it. Just the remnants of something that once was.

I can loop through the images, but not sure how to use the "r", "s", etc key to move the image to specific directories. Ideally with a unique sound for a successful move. PHP, javascript, or java would be ok. Although I am a newby with Java in Netbeans.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to move selected files between folders ex. `copy()` and `unlink()` as something like this:

```
move.php?file=FOTO001.jpg&folder=A
move.php?file=FOTO004.jpg&folder=BBB
```

And trigger this by `javascript` for example with `jQuery` via ajax.

And this can provide you keyboard shourcuts : https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Comment: Here is what I have thus far. It seems to work, but not sure how to view images from command line PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have another thread on the same code going with a more specific question. I will end this thread and point you to  "How to view jpg images with a command line PHP program" thread. thanks